# Can we set AWS ALB priorities through AWS Console?

Tags: aws-application-load-balancer

I wasn't able to find a way to set the rule priorities for ALB through AWS Console. Can we set AWS ALB priorities through AWS Console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was able to figure out that the order in which the rules are defined under a listener is the priority